# service based database run in another PC

Tags: c#, sql-server-express

I have been working on a project related to database (.mdf). I have created some windows forms in visual studio using C#. Basically these forms work together to store, update and delete data from the Service Based Database i created.when I run this project in another PC there is problem in connection to data base,I change the connection string as in another PC but the smae problem.

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder s = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=H:\\PDF_to_TEXT_PROJECT_MBRM\\PDF-to-Text Convertor\\PDF-to-Text Convertor\\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
```

can you tell me how solve this problem?
this error:
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file H:\PDF_to_TEXT_PROJECT_MBRM\PDF-to-Text Convertor\PDF-to-Text Convertor\Database1.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: What is the problem you are having, are you getting an exception, is the data it returns not what you expected, does it crash windows with a blue-screen? Please provide details of what is going wrong, there is a few things I could guess is wrong but it would be better if you told us what was going wrong instead of us guessing.

Comment: Why not put the connection string in the configuration?
This would avoid you from having to recompile between machines.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233%28v=vs.100%29.aspx